# How functions are organised in functional programming languages like Haskell or Clojure?

Tags: java, oop, haskell, clojure, functional-programming

My understanding is that in FP you have a lot of functions working on a few pre-defined data types.

So it's possible to have, for example, 10 different functions called `prepare_data` each of which acting on a different data type. (e.g. `prepare_data` for Customer, Company, Resource, ...).
So when you see a call to `prepare_data` function in the code, how can a developer find the definition of that function?

I am coming from OOP background and in OOP when you see something like `myObject.prepare_data` you can find the definition by looking at the source code file for `MyObject` class, which can uniquely be identified (where `MyObject` is the type of `myObject`). But in FP the code for `prepare_data` can be located in any of source files in the system. So how is this done in FP?

Comment: Depends on the language. There is usually some form of tooling that can locate an arbitrary identifier’s definition, but it varies between different languages.

Comment: So you need a tool to do that, right? For example if you are using a normal text editor or browsing the code from internet, there is no easy way to find source code?

Comment: You can read the imports. Good tooling makes programming easier, though, and I would always encourage using it when it’s available. Writing Java productively without an IDE is nearly impossible. (Also, it’s worth pointing out that the type of `myObject` is not enough to determine the location of `prepare_data` in the presence of subtyping/inheritance.)

Comment: In Java, the class `MyObject` is always defined in `MyObject.java`. In other languages, there isn't necessarily an obvious place to look for the definition of `MyObject`.

Comment: That's too broad a question. Depends entirely on the language, and has nothing to do with functional programming. The way different languages deal with namespaces, modules, packages etc. has nothing to do with them being functional or not. You need to search and have tooling support - precisely like in Java. If you have a bunch of imports in your class and have a reference to another class called `PrepareData`, how would you know what package it belongs to without searching or using your IDE?

Comment: @YuriSteinschreiber I just search for a file named `PrepareData.java`. To find subclasses I grep for `extends PrepareData`. This is completely doable without an IDE or even on a web interface like GitHub.

Comment: @mahdix - you may have missed the point. There may be multiple files named `PrepareData.java`, in different packages, maybe in your project, maybe in some jars your projects refers to. How would you know which one to look for? You will have to scan through the packages in your imports, or rely on IDE to tell you where it is. The point is it is not trivial even in Java, in C# it's already more complicated (you can have multiple classes in the same file.) In short, OOP doesn't make it easier or different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, frankly, you sometimes *can't* find the source. Which is BTW no different in OO languages – it may simply not be supplied. All you have, in general, is the interface / header file / signature.

More than in OO, the type signature in a strongly typed functional language can really tell you a lot about how to use a function. Often, you won't need any documentation nor source code, you just need to look at the type signature and know what this function is good for and how to use it, simply because there's *only one way* the types can match.

To find the type signature, most languages will offer you some tool to look it up. In Haskell, you can load the file in question into [GHCi](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html), and then query

```
YourModule> :i prepare_data
```

which would print out the type signature (and indeed also the module in which this function is defined).

That said, there is in practice a rather more efficient way to get at the signatures, documentation and if necessary also source code: search the internet! In the case of Haskell, there are a couple of great specialised search engines. If you ask [Hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) the name of a function like `prepare_data`, it will search the entire Hackage database (where basically all relevant open-source Haskell projects are hosted) for functions of that name. If the name isn't particularly generic, you should see the correct one on the first page, linked to the documentation with signature, which in turn also has the source code linked online.

If the function name by itself is too ambiguous, you can limit the search to the library in question (you hopefully know that already!) or look up the module directly. As I said, you may learn this from a tool like GHCi, but often it can in fact be seem right from the code: no matter if it's a class or a bunch of functions, *they always need to be imported before use*<sup>†</sup>. So you have at the top of your file something like

```
import MyData
import MyData.Algorithms
import MyData.Util
```

which already gives you quite strong hints. You may even have each entity explicitly mentioned:

```
import MyData(MyData)
import MyData.Algorithms(foo, bar)
import MyData.Util(baz, prepare_data) -- gotcha!
```

Depends on the language how common this is.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>There are a few languages that do it different, for example Matlab will just search for a *file of that name* if it encounters a function. Which really works completely horribly badly; fortunately most other languages *do* require explicit imports.</sub>